# 2011 Chevy Traverse Dash Lights Up, Won't Turn Over, No Clicking Noise

Tags: traverse

I have a 2011 Chevy Traverse. It worked fine lastnight when I got home. This morning I go to open my vehicle and there is no power to the dashboard, interior lights, key fob won't unlock doors.

No power in dashboard, until I turn my key to start my vehicle. Lights on the dash light up but the car doesn't start. It doesn't even try to start. No clicking noise, no attempt to turn over. Nothing!

Comment: What is the battery voltage? Use a volt meter.

Comment: The battery is fine. I had it tested at the shop. They can't figure out what is wrong with it either.